# Keeping maps in sync across two tabs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, mkmapview

I have several tabs in my interface. One of which displays a map. Another tab should display the same map (same lat, long, region etc), but only in certain circumstances. How would I keep these maps in sync? I guess this could be a more general question about keeping data in sync across several tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either have a singleton that both tabs can access to store and retrieve data about the map or save it to file, perhaps via NSData. The second option will allow persistence of the data across launches.

Comment: I guess it would make sense for a singleton to save to a file, and also to icloud eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Consider having your map data at some place **from where** it could be available across all your tabs, So you could have an singleton class,which will hold your map data and you could the map data access that across tabs.